# Build Error in React Native Android App After Ejecting from Expo: Multiple Kotlin Plugin Loads and Java Compilation Failures

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle

I was making this application using expo and then i needed to eject from it so now my application is using barebones react-native.

```
gradlew clean
```

works fine but when i try to run npm run android. it is giving me error which i can't seem to understand what is.
The error is as follows

```
PS D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android> .\gradlew clean       

> Configure project :app
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.4.14)

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-application (5.3.1)
  - expo-constants (14.4.2)
  - expo-dev-client (2.4.12)
  - expo-dev-launcher (2.4.14)
  - expo-dev-menu (3.2.2)
  - expo-file-system (15.4.4)
  - expo-font (11.4.0)
  - expo-json-utils (0.7.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (12.3.0)
  - expo-linear-gradient (12.3.0)
  - expo-manifests (0.7.2)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core (1.5.11)
  - expo-secure-store (12.3.1)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.20.5)


The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core', ':react-native-gesture-handler', ':react-native-safe-area-context', ...

> Task :expo-modules-core:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug
Clean expo-modules-core-armeabi-v7a
Clean expo-modules-core-arm64-v8a

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
38 actionable tasks: 28 executed, 10 up-to-date
PS D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android> cd ..
PS D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native> npm run android 

> jiroun-app@1.0.0 android
> expo run:android

env: load .env
env: export EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL EXPO_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT_URL
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.4.14)

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-application (5.3.1)
  - expo-constants (14.4.2)
  - expo-dev-client (2.4.12)
  - expo-dev-launcher (2.4.14)
  - expo-dev-menu (3.2.2)
  - expo-file-system (15.4.4)
  - expo-font (11.4.0)
  - expo-json-utils (0.7.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (12.3.0)
  - expo-linear-gradient (12.3.0)
  - expo-manifests (0.7.2)
  - expo-modules-core (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.5.11)
  - expo-secure-store (12.3.1)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.20.5)


The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core', ':react-native-gesture-handler', ':react-native-safe-area-context', ...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainActivity.java:19: error: package R does not exist
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
              ^
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainActivity.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainActivity
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
               ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!BuildConfig.REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS) {
         ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:67: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
       ^
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\ibefehdi\jirounapp\MainApplication.java:71: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       ^
10 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
338 actionable tasks: 61 executed, 267 from cache, 10 up-to-date
Error: D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1                                                     
Error: D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1                                                     
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)           
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:26)                                                                                                         
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)                                                                                                          
    at cp.emit (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)      
    at runAndroidAsync (D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
PS D:\jiroun-workflow\jiroun-app-react-native> `

This is my build.gradle
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'
        // compileSdkVersion =33
        // targetSdkVersion =33
        // minSdkVersion= 21

        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and this is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

def projectRoot = rootDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    entryFile = file(["node", "-e", "require('expo/scripts/resolveAppEntry')", projectRoot, "android", "absolute"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    reactNativeDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()
    hermesCommand = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc"
    codegenDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native/codegen/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()

    // Use Expo CLI to bundle the app, this ensures the Metro config
    // works correctly with Expo projects.
    cliFile = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@expo/cli')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    bundleCommand = "export:embed"

    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]

    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = (findProperty('android.enableProguardInReleaseBuilds') ?: false).toBoolean()

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.jirounapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ibefehdi.jirounapp'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

// Apply static values from `gradle.properties` to the `android.packagingOptions`
// Accepts values in comma delimited lists, example:
// android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts=/LICENSE,**/picasa.ini
["pickFirsts", "excludes", "merges", "doNotStrip"].each { prop ->
    // Split option: 'foo,bar' -> ['foo', 'bar']
    def options = (findProperty("android.packagingOptions.$prop") ?: "").split(",");
    // Trim all elements in place.
    for (i in 0..<options.size()) options[i] = options[i].trim();
    // `[] - ""` is essentially `[""].filter(Boolean)` removing all empty strings.
    options -= ""

    if (options.length > 0) {
        println "android.packagingOptions.$prop += $options ($options.length)"
        // Ex: android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts += '**/SCCS/**'
        options.each {
            android.packagingOptions[prop] += it
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6")

    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";
    def frescoVersion = rootProject.ext.frescoVersion

    // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
    if (isGifEnabled || isWebpEnabled) {
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:${frescoVersion}")
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:${frescoVersion}")
    }

    if (isGifEnabled) {
        // For animated gif support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:${frescoVersion}")
    }

    if (isWebpEnabled) {
        // For webp support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:${frescoVersion}")
        if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
            // Animated webp support
            implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:${frescoVersion}")
        }
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Looking at another question on stackoverflow i included the react-native version in my package.json to the app/build.gradle but this has not fixed my error.